# Delete / backspace within dbaccess will not delete characters

Tags: informix, dbaccess

Using dbaccess via SSH into a fedora server.  When I go to Query - New, both backspace and delete do not have an effect.

How can I set up the environment to work with delete/backspace?  They work fine in vi.

Edit: Some more info.  CTRL-H in vi deletes the previous characer (same as backspace).  CTRL-H in dbaccess moves the cursor left one character but does not delete anything.

Comment: What you describe is a bit odd.  Have you compared the terminal settings (`stty -a`) for the successful `vi` environment and the DB-Access environment?  Can you go from `vi` to `dbaccess` in the same terminal session and it works in `vi` and fails in `dbaccess`?  What is the size of the window?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler yep, same session, works in vi but not dbaccess.  Size of window is 80 cols, 63 lines.

Comment: Have you set INFORMIXTERM=terminfo?  It should not affect this - but there's an outside chance it might.

Comment: @Jonathan just tried that, unfortunately no change.

Comment: it appears i'm just going to have to learn to use ctrl-x :)

Comment: Yuck...have you looked at the output from `stty -a`?  What does it show as the erase character?  What is your TERM setting?  What about TERMINFO, or TERMCAP?  I would set `DBEDIT=vi` (or `DBEDIT=vim`) in your environment and then DB-Access will use that to edit SQL - as long as you remember to use the Use-Editor option.  I don't like DB-Access all that much; I don't use it because I wrote [SQLCMD](http://www.iiug.org/software/) over 20 years ago, and it does what I want the way I want it to do it.

Comment: stty -a shows erase = ^?;  TERM = xterm;  TERMINFO is empty; TERMCAP is /etc/termcap.fc4;   Use-Editor crashes with Vi unfortunately, when vi is finished, it doesnt hand back to dbaccess properly and you have to kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution!  I was using Putty, and the default settings under Terminal-Keyboard was Control-? (127) for backspace.  When I set this to Control-H, the cursor in DBAccess goes left one character.  It does not remove the character, but this is better than doing nothing at all.